# WiX Variable bal:Overridable="yes" being ignored

Tags: wix, burn

My bundle, has reference to WixBalExtension:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi" xmlns:bal="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/BalExtension">
  <Bundle Compressed="yes" Name="My App" Version="$(var.Version)" Manufacturer="My Company" UpgradeCode="{GUID HERE}">
    <Variable Name="LAUNCHAFTERINSTALL" Type="numeric" bal:Overridable="yes" Value="0"/>
```

The bundle log:

```
[3A24:3A84][2013-10-20T22:39:30]i001: Burn v3.7.1224.0, Windows v6.1 (Build 7601: Service Pack 1), path: D:\myapp.exe, cmdline: 'LAUNCHAFTERINSTALL=1 -log "D:\myapp.exe.log"'
[3A24:3A84][2013-10-20T22:39:30]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'LAUNCHAFTERINSTALL' to value '0'
```

Why is bal:Overridable="yes" being ignored, or at least not accepting the command line parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WixStdBA has logic to set variables from the command line; it obeys Overridable. If you're using a custom bootstrapper application, it has to do the work.

Comment: I'm modifying WixBA to make my own custom manager installer interface. I can access `WixBA.Model.Command.GetCommandLineArgs()` and `WixBA.Model.Engine.StringVariables` so I can parse them both but I see nothing about overridable attributes - this means it's not available I guess?

Comment: It's a feature of WixStdBA: If you don't mark the variable as overridable, WixStdBA will ignore it so you can decide whether users can override variables in your bundle.